# <g:select> issue with a lot of data in grails 1.3.7

Tags: grails

I use grails 1.3.7. I have a class A which has a one to one relation to class B. By default, the static scaffolding generate a `<g:select>` component to manage this relation on Class A referential screen.

But I have plenty instance of Class B so when I try to expend the component, my navigator freezes (I try to load all the class B instance I think) !

One solution could be to Ajax-ify my component and made a kind of pajinated request but I think there is a easier way (another strategy, component ?)

Do someone have any idea on this issue ?

Also the best would be to have a component where the user can also filter the Class B component with it's attributes. Not sure it already exists in grails ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery's Autocomplete or typeAhead of Twitter bootstrap.

Comment: I think these components will allow me to filter some results in order to show them on the component. I will try this strategy but I need to change my screen conception for that.